# Pushing Data to a MySQL Database from a Form

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to send data from an HTML form to a MySQL database in phpmyadmin. I have a database named bhs[image]2018 and a table called game 1. Here are the contents of that table.

Here is my form:

```
<form name="game" action="insert.php" method="post">
  <p> <select id="player" name = 'player'>
    <option value="b">B</option>
    <option value="n">N</option>
    <option value="a">A</option>
    <option value="c">C</option>
    <option value="m">M</option>
    <option value="j">J</option>
    <option value="ja">Ja</option>

  </select>
  <select id="what" name = 'what'>
    <option value="shoton">Shot on Cage</option>
    <option value="shotoff">Shot off Cage</option>
    <option value="goal">Goal</option>
    <option value="countergoal">Goal on Counter</option>
    <option value="countershot">Shot on Counter</option>
    <option value="assist">Assist</option>
    <option value="block">Block</option>
    <option value="steal">Steal</option>
    <option value="turnover">Turnover</option>
    <option value="drawn">Ejection Drawn</option>
    <option value="ejected">Ejected</option>
  </select>
  <select id="where" name = 'where'>
    <option value="set">Set</option>
    <option value="navy">Navy</option>
    <option value="leftwing">1/2 side past 5</option>
    <option value="rightwing">4/5 side past 5</option>
    <option value="point">Point/3</option>
    <option value="lefttwo">1/2 side 2 meter</option>
    <option value="righttwo">4/5 side 2 meter</option>
    <option value="1">6 on 5 1</option>
    <option value="2">6 on 5 2</option>
    <option value="3">6 on 5 3</option>
    <option value="4">6 on 5 4</option>
    <option value="5">6 on 5 5</option>
    <option value="6">6 on 5 6</option>
  </select>
  <select id="quarter" name = 'quarter'>
    <option value="q1">Quarter 1</option>
    <option value="q2">Quarter 2</option>
    <option value="q3">Quarter 3</option>
    <option value="q4">Quarter 4</option>
  </select>
    <select id="time" name = 'time'>
    <option value="0:30">0:30</option>
    <option value="1:00">1:00</option>
    <option value="1:30">1:30</option>
    <option value="2:00">2:00</option>
    <option value="2:30">2:30</option>
    <option value="3:00">3:00</option>
    <option value="3:30">3:30</option>
    <option value="4:00">4:00</option>
    <option value="4:30">4:30</option>
    <option value="5:00">5:00</option>
    <option value="5:30">5:30</option>
    <option value="6:00">6:00</option>
    <option value="6:30">6:30</option>
    <option value="7:00">7:00</option>
  </select>

  Notes: <input type="text" id = 'notes' name = 'notes'>

  <button type="submit" onclick="save()"> Save </button> </p>
</form>
```

Whenever I click my "Save" button, the insert.php script loads. Instead of echoing something, it just shows the code. Here is insert.php.

```
<?php
    $con = mysqli_connect('127.0.0.1','root','password'(my actual password is here);
    if(!$con){
        echo 'Not Connected to Server';
    }

    if (!mysqli_select_db($con,'bhs2018')){
            echo 'Not Selected';
    }

    $Player = $_POST['player'];
    $Quarter = $_POST['quarter'];
    $Time = $_POST['time'];
    $Where = $_POST['where'];
    $Notes = $_POST['notes'];
    $What = $_POST['what'];

    $sql = "INSERT INTO game1 (player,quarter,time1,where1,notes,what) VALUES ('$Player', '$Quarter', '$Time', '$Where','$Notes','$What')";
    if(!mysqli_query($con,$sql)){
        echo'Not Inserted';
    }
    else{
        echo 'Inserted';
    }

    header('refresh:2; url=index.html');


?>
```

What is looking wrong with my code? Why does it not run the php script? Thank you so much!

Comment: what is the problem do you get any error

Comment: @sanojlawrence There is no error message. I just see the insert.php script in a browser window.

Comment: how do run `PHP`..? do you use `WAMP` or `Xampp`..?

Comment: @sanojlawrence I am using apache.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. You should use prepared statements with bound parameters, via either [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). [**This post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) has some good examples.

Comment: try changing `<button type="submit" onclick="save()"> Save </button>` to `<input type="submit" name="submit">`

Comment: @AlexHowansky To make it invulnerable, I just need to add "mysql_real_escape_string" before each variable?

Comment: No, `mysql_real_escape_string()` is not always sufficient. You must use prepared statements with bound parameters.

Comment: I ran your code in my personal webserver and everything worked fine.

Although, I did make a few changes since I am on a local server. I changed the server to "localhost" and I changed the password.

Are you running this on a local server?

Comment: @sanojlawrence This did not end up working :(.

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh I am running this on a local server. I believe something is wrong with my setup. I have php running (it shows the screen when I go to https/localhost), mysql running, apache running, and phpmyadmin running. Do I need something else running?

Comment: You should not be logging into your mysql server with Root, that's a huge security breach (Unless this application is not public), but that won't fix your problem.

Comment: @TejSingh Try changing your ip to localhost.

Comment: Is your file a `.php` file?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton This app is not public, I am using it for learning. And it is a .php file.

Comment: @FaridKaradsheh That won't really solve OPs problem, because OP said it's just displaying the PHP code in the webpage, meaning it is not executing.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton Well, I think he stated it is downloading the file. So, it may be that his local server is off.

Comment: @Tej Singh, check your database. Your `PRIMARY KEY`  `player` should be an `integer` like `int(30)` or `bigint(200)` but not `varchar`. Create and new column for `PRIMARY KEY`.  Also when primary key is an integer, there is no manual insertion option for inputting it's value  in your form. So make your primary key is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Answer (score 0):

Check your database. Your `PRIMARY KEY` `player` should be an `integer` like `int(30)` or `bigint(200)` but not `varchar`. Create a new column for `PRIMARY KEY` something like `player_id` and shift `player` to next column. Also when primary key is an integer, there is no manual insertion option for inputting it's value in your form. So make your `PRIMARY KEY` is set to `AUTO_INCREMENT` in case you don't want to insert it's value manually.